# Setting up VMs on different subnets

Tags: networking, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, routing, network-bridge

I run a server on IP X.Y.3.7 and i want to run multiple VMs on it using libvirt.

I set up a bridge device:

```
auto  eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
address   X.Y.3.7
broadcast X.Y.3.31
netmask   255.255.255.224
gateway   X.Y.3.1
bridge_ports none
bridge_ports eth0
...
```

Everything works smoothly if use the first of my three additional IPs:
X.Y.3.9

However, the other 2 are from a different subnet
X.Y.4.101
X.Y.4.102

The bridged network approach does not seem to work with Guest from different subnets? What alternatives do i have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `br0` bridge only routes traffic in your `X.Y.3.0/27` subnet.

You ought to create another bridge interface for your second subnet, *or* expand the size of your `br0` netmask.

For example, you could make another bridge, `br1`. You'd need to use `255.255.255.248` as your netmask in order to use X.Y.4.101 as a host IP; if you instead use `255.255.255.252`, X.Y.4.101 would be your default gateway.

```
auto br1
iface br1 inet static
address   X.Y.4.100
netmask   255.255.255.248
gateway   X.Y.4.97
broadcast X.Y.4.103
bridge_ports eth0
```

If you want to join those two subnets into one which all use the same bridge interface (that is, you are not using any IP addresses from that new, larger subnet anywhere else) you can simply recalculate an appropriate netmask and broadcast address:

```
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
address   X.Y.3.7
broadcast X.Y.7.255
netmask   255.255.248.0
gateway   X.Y.3.1
bridge_ports none
bridge_ports eth0
```

The disadvantage of using this second approach is that you wind up creating one very large subnet of 2048 address, from X.Y.0.0 - X.Y.7.255

If you were willing to do some tinkering with your routing table (and I cannot recommend this suggestion, as it would break CIDR-style notation and routing) you could create a more-complicated netmask for such a subnet, excluding more IP addresses That's generally a bad idea for a whole bunch of reasons.

Comment: My ISP only assigned me 2 Addresses from the X.Y.4 network - 101 and 102. I suppose i would get in serious trouble if i used 100 as the address of my interface.
I checked back with them and found out that they routed the additional addresses on my host address and assigned MAC adresses to the IPs. Now i can simply configure my guests with DHCP and get the addresses automatically.

Comment: What about setting up those additional VMs behind a NAT address at 101 or 102, and then port-forwarding? it's not precisely the same, but it gets you a bit of administrative flexibility. Anyway, I'm glad to hear you were able to get your trouble sorted out